# What is the mistake in this script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, hashlib, cracking

How to fix this script is not showing any data:

Here is my code:

```
from hashlib import md5
counter = 1
pass_in = input('Enter the md5 hash: ')
pwfile = input('Please enter the passowrd file: ')

try:
    pwfile = open(pwfile,'r')
except:
    print('\nfile not found')
    quit()
for password in pwfile:
    filemd5 = md5()
    filemd5.update(password.strip().encode('utf-8'))
    filemd5.hexdigest()
    print('Trying password number')
    counter += 1

    if pass_in == filemd5:
        print('\n Match Found. \nPassword is: %s' + password)
        break
else:
    print('\n password not found!')
```

What did i forget?

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filemd5.hexdigest()` doesn't transform the hash object into a string, it returns a string. Change that line to `filemd5 = filemd5.hexdigest()`.

Also in `print('\n Match Found. \nPassword is: %s' + password)` change the `+` to a `%`.

Comment: still getting same output

Comment: @HamzaMirchi here is a demo of it working: https://repl.it/repls/DefinitiveGraciousInstance . If it doesn't work for you it probably means you're not entering an md5 hash that corresponds to a password in your password file.

Comment: Where i can password file?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: misread your question. Alex's answer is correct, this works (updated to show working code without a file):

```
from hashlib import md5
counter = 1
pass_in = input('Enter the md5 hash: ')  # use "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592"

for password in ['hello',]:
    filemd5 = md5()
    filemd5.update(password.strip().encode('utf-8'))
    filemd5 = filemd5.hexdigest()  # THIS LINE IS YOUR PROBLEM
    print('Trying password number')
    counter += 1

    if pass_in == filemd5:
        print('\n Match Found. \nPassword is: %s' + password)
        break
else:
    print('\n password not found!')
```

Comment: means? how to fix

Comment: Updated my answer, but I re-read your code and I guess you're expecting the user to know the md5 hash of the password? That's weird...if the passwords are stored unhashed, and the user is looking for the password, why bother with all the hashing? It doesn't really provide any security.